# Solana websockets freezes while waiting for response

Tags: go, websocket, solana

I tried to create function to send and confirm transaction on solana blockchain, but in some cases it looks like it freezes while waiting from sub.Recv() response. Hope to get any clue why is that and how can I add any sort of timeout for that. Thanks in advance.

```
func SendAndConfirmTx(
   tpuClient *tpu.TPUClient,
   wsClient *ws.Client,
   transaction *solana.Transaction,
) (signature solana.Signature, err error) {

sig, err := tpuClient.SendTransaction(transaction,50)
if err != nil {
    return sig, err
}

sub, err := wsClient.SignatureSubscribe(
    sig,
    rpc.CommitmentConfirmed,
)
if err != nil {
    return sig, err
}
defer sub.Unsubscribe()

for {
    got, err := sub.Recv()
    if err != nil {
        return sig, err
    }
    if got.Value.Err != nil {
        return sig, fmt.Errorf("transaction confirmation failed: %v", got.Value.Err)
    } else {
        return sig, nil
    }
  }
}
```